# Angular 2 - EXCEPTION: Expression 'ngClassUntouched has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

The full error message is:

> angular2.dev.js:23597 EXCEPTION: Expression 'ngClassUntouched in
>   myComponent@7:12' has changed after it was checked. Previous value:
>   'true'. Current value: 'false' in [ngClassUntouched in
>   MyComponent@7:12]

The error points to this control:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchTxt" class="searchText" type="text" 
class="form-control" placeholder="Search all departments & sites"
(keypress)="handleKeyboard($event)" [ngClass]="{noBorder: tags.length >     
0}" (keyup)="handleKeyboard($event)" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Basically, this occurs on the keyup event when I execute the following command to change the focus from searchTxt to the dynamically created input:

```
this.inputs.toArray()[0].nativeElement.focus();
```

More details: This is the dynamically created array of inputs:

```
<div *ngFor="#item of records?.data">
<input #input name="r{{item.id}}" class="focusInputBox" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Those inputs is a result of:

```
@ViewChildren('input') inputs;
```

Any suggestions ?

ty !!!

**UPDATE:** I noticed that angular added few classes on the searchTxt: class="form-control searchText ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty"

the ng-untouched raises into searchTxt got added when I set the focus of the input boxes.

Comment: How do you load your list of tags? Thanks!

Comment: This is incomplete information. please come up with more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap focus() in `setTimeout(...)` this is what causes the class to be set at a time Angular doesn't expect a change:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.inputs.toArray()[0].nativeElement.focus();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Nope :( Nothing related...by the way..check my update. and I made few researches and looks like something is happening on the change detection, but I was unable to understand.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Wow ! it's works !! Ty !! But do you mind why this caused this and how this fix the solution ?

Comment: I would need to see where `...focus()` is called from. Seems like it is called from something that is initiated by Angulars change detection. Angular doesn't like it when it's change detection changes the state. When a change is caused by `setTimeout()` (which is patched by Angulars NgZone), then Angular is fine with it. Therefore we postpone the change so it doesn't happen during Angulars chang detection and make it happen in a `setTimeout()` where Angular is fine with it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component and calls its `detectChanges` method:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

The call of this method could be done in another place since it depends on the way you load your tags...

Comment: Ty, Thiery ! Gunter gave me the solution, but I will try in your way as well to make the things in a different perspective.